# Convert MS Office file to PDF, using edraw office viewer component OCX and javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-office

How can I save a MS Office file as a PDF, using edraw office viewer component OCX and javascript?

hint : I have installed the Addon *SaveAsPDF* to my office.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Open method to open the file. Then call the SaveAs method to export as PDF format.

EDOffice1.Open "path", "Word.Application"

EDOffice1.SaveAs "newpath", 17      //wdFormatPDF = 17,

Answer (score 0):

You need not the `Adobe Addon`. But the end user need to install `MS Office 2010/2013/2016` version. Call the SaveAs method to save the opened office files as the PDF format.

If you want to save the word file to pdf, you can use the following javascript code:

```
axedoffice.SaveAs(path,17);
```